# Socket.io not disconnecting, xhr-polling 400 bad request

Tags: angularjs, sockets, socket.io

Io and Angular. When a page is refreshed the disconnect event in socket.io is not fired. I've done some research online which has led me to implement the following

`io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);`

However when this is set I get the following error;

GET http://app.local:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1448414100223-67 400 (Bad Request)

I have the following code;

server.js

```
var express =   require('express'),
    http =      require('http'),
    server =    http.createServer(app),
    path = require('path'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

const redis =   require('redis');
const io =      require('socket.io').listen(server);
const client =  redis.createClient();

server.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');

io.listen(server).on('connection', function(client) {
    const redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('user.joined');
    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
        client.emit(channel, message);
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    });
});
io.set('transports', ['xhr-polling']);
```

Angular code;

```
var serverBaseUrl = 'http://app.local:3000';
myApp.factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {
    var myIoSocket = io.connect(serverBaseUrl, {'sync disconnect on unload' : true});

    var socket = socketFactory({
        ioSocket: myIoSocket
    });

    return socket;
});
```

any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, yes, this may happen, unfortunatelly, `polling` is rather.. *fail-safe* transport and should be used if any others fails.

First of all I recommend to define several transports for socket to use.

```
// server
io.set('transports', [ 'websocket', 'flashsocket', 'polling' ] );

// client
io.connect( "/", { secure: true, transports: [ "flashsocket","polling","websocket" ] } );
```

The order how you defined them will matter - socket.io will try to use them in the corresponding order as you defined. By the way, since `socket.io` 1.0 it's `polling` not `xhr-polling`.

And to minimize cases of not receiving `disconnect` event I can recomment to use browser windows's `onbeforeunload` event and add something like this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    console.log( "unloading resources" );   
    $scope.socket.disconnect();
    $scope.socket.close();
};
```

You can add this event handler just after you received `connect` event on client side.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get this error now; `WebSocket connection to 'ws://app.local:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=UccSYaNjJl4j_Pp7AAAA' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response` any ideas?

Comment: Instead of `io.listen(server).on('connection', function(client) {..` try `io.on('connection', function(client) {`. It may occur if you defined io.listen twice.

Comment: In server I am using client transports: [ 'flashsocket', 'polling', 'websocket', 'xhr-polling' ] and in server as  ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'polling', 'xhr-polling'] .In browser I am getting the same websocket connection error.In server I am using as 'io=socketio.listen(server, properties);io.on('connection', onSocketConnection);'